# Spring Boot JPA returns List of List not List of Object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot jpa. I would like to get return type as List but I am getting just List

My Entity Class

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERDB.USERS")
public class User() {
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_SEQ_NAME", allocationSize = 1), name = "MY_SEQ")
  @Column(name = "userId")
  private long id;
  @Column(name = "firstName")
  private String fName;
  @Column(name = "midName")
  private String mName;
  @Column(name = "lastName")
  private String lName;
  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;
  @Column(name = "createdDate")
  private Timestamp createdOn;

public User() {
    this.createdOn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()
}

//SETTERS & GETTERS

}
```

My Repository;

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

  @Query("SELECT id fName, lastName, email FROM User u WHERE u.fName=(:fName)")
  public List<User> findByEmail(@Param("fName") String fName);

}
```

All I wanted is to get a json response as a User Array with key value pair like below

```
    [
   [
     "id": 1001,
     "fName": John",
     "lName": "Doe",
     "email": "johnd@example.com"       
   ],
   [
     "id": 1002,
     "fName": "John",
     "lName": "Simmons",
     "email": "johns@example.com"       
   ],

]
```

but I am getting a list with just values as below.

```
[
   [
     1001,
     "John",
     "Doe",
     "johnd@example.com"       
   ],
   [
     1002,
     "John",
     "Simmons",
     "johns@example.com"       
   ],

]
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong or is this how I am supposed to get ? This is a hypothetical example of my actual program. Please excuse me for any errors.

Here is my controller class

```
@Restcontroller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
UserRepository repo;
@GetMapping("/user/{fname}")
  public List<User> getUserByName(
         @PathVariable("fname") String fname) {

  return repo.findByEmail(fname);
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: You aren't getting alist of users but alist of columns. For each row you get a list of values from the columns, instead of a `User` object. So either just retrieve the user, and send that or use a [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

Answer (score 0):

A few points on your code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

   Query("SELECT id fName, lastName, email FROM User u WHERE u.fName=(:fName)")
   public List<User> findEmails(@Param("fName") String fName);

 }
```

You are creating the repository with `JpaRepository<User, String>` but in your class `User` id is not of type `String`. Consider making the ID field a String.

The method is `findEmails` but it is returning a `List<User>`? I would expect such a function to return `List<String>` - each string of course being an email. You may consider renaming this function to avoid future confusion. Not a big deal though.

In your query:

`@Query("SELECT id fName, lastName, email FROM User u WHERE u.fName=(:fName)")`

You should change this to:

`@Query("SELECT u.id u.fName, u.lastName, u.email FROM User u WHERE u.fName=(:fName)")`

That should fix the serialization issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please dont loo much into the code as just coded a sample application here in stackoverflow. All I wanted is a json array of object with key value pair.

Comment: Ok no problem! Let me know if the query update doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry did not change anything. I am still getting List<List<String>>

Answer (score 0):

I very much agree with the suggestion of Fermi-4. Using a better naming convention is key to have a better easy manageable code. You should follow them. To solve your problem, just do the following and it will solve your problem.

```
   public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, long> {


  public List<User> findByFname(String fName);

 }
```

Also, consider changing USER Entity definition to add serializable implementation as below

```
    @Component
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USERDB.USERS")    
    public class User implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
```

Comment: thank you Abhishek, but my actual code is  different and I need to use custom Query. Yes I did implement Serializable. Sorry its for my work so I could not paste my actual codes here

Answer (score 0):

1. Create additional `User` constructor with only few arguments that you wish to fetch from table

```java
public User(long id, String fName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
```

2. Adjust JP query like following

```java
@Query("SELECT new com.package.User(u.id, u.fName, u.lastName, u.email) FROM User u WHERE u.fName = :fName")
public List<User> findByEmail(@Param("fName") String fName);
```

replace `com.package` with your `User`'s actual package